# javascript .file trouble

Tags: javascript, html

I'm getting undefined when I alert this

```
document.getElementById('imgtype').files[0];
```

from this input

```
<input type="file" name='imgtype' id='imgtype'  style="margin-top: 20px;" />
```

Am I using it wrong the files???

here's the whole function

```
function fileUp(imgtype) {
  var fdata = new FormData();
  alert(document.getElementById(imgtype).files);
  fdata.append("Upload", document.getElementById(imgtype).files[0]);
  fdata.append("type", imgtype);
  fdata.append("reg_id", document.getElementById('reg_id').value);

  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", uploadProgress, false);
  xhr.addEventListener("load", uploadComplete, false);
  xhr.addEventListener("error", uploadFailed, false);
  xhr.addEventListener("abort", uploadCanceled, false);
  xhr.open("POST", "upload.php");
  xhr.send(fdata);
}
```

imgtype is the input file id and name

Comment: What exactly do you want to do?

Comment: im getting the input file to be uploaded

Comment: You can't upload files with AJAX. You'd have to use an `<iframe>` or a Flash uploader.

Comment: What do you click to execute fileUp(imgtype)  ?

Comment: Are you using the right API then? (The HTML 5 file API) And what browser(s) are you trying this in?